# undo a gzip recursively

Tags: zip, gzip

OK, so I did a stupid, and forgot to specify a filename in the process of doing a website backup.

Now, all my files say file_name.extn.*gz*

How do I get all those mistakenly gzipped files back to normal?

I've tried tar, unzip, etc but not successful. The directories are not .gz, only each file inside.

System is 14.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What `gzip -r` does, `gunzip -r` undoes:

```
$ gzip foo -r
$ find foo 
foo
foo/d
foo/d/1.gz
foo/a
foo/a/3.gz
$ gunzip -r foo
$ find foo     
foo
foo/d
foo/d/1
foo/a
foo/a/3
```

Comment: So simple, yet couldn't find it anywhere online. Worked for me, thanks.

Comment: I did the same dumb thing to my website and this saved my butt. Thanks guys! The important lesson I learned here is to use Tar to zip your whole site up, not Gzip.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93139/can-i-zip-an-entire-folder-using-gzip

Comment: Brilliant. Wow. Thank you.